# ajax code for retriving data from db is correct still cant display the specific result which is searched for on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb

my project is a todo list website. in which I have added a search page where a task can be searched. task with day date time will be displayed, the code for that seems correct to my knowledge but it just displays the whole list instead of what the user wants to search for
this is the Ajax code:

```js
type function showSearchResults() {
        
        // Use AJAX to submit the form asynchronously
        var form = document.getElementById("searchForm");
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", form.action + "?" + new URLSearchParams(formData).toString(), true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            console.log('Search Results Received:', xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("searchResults").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("allHistory").style.display = "none";
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    function showAllHistory() {
        
        // Use AJAX to submit the form asynchronously
        var form = document.getElementById("allHistoryForm");
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", form.action + "?" + new URLSearchParams(formData).toString(), true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            console.log('All History Received:', xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("allHistory").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("searchResults").style.display = "none";
        };
        xhr.send();
    }here
```

I inspected it in the developer's tool to see if it is getting the right data. I found it is successfully getting the right data. but for some unknown reason, it always displays the whole list of data  no matter what user searches for
this is a screenshot from developer tool
[image]

please help

Comment: Are you using some sort of templationg language to build the webpage? Like EJS or PHP?

Comment: yes i am its ejs

Comment: Ok. You should redirect the user to the desired page instead of ajax, and also in ejs chage the display: none dependant on if the user reqursted specific search